# WatiN unable to find textbox by id nor name

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, watin

I have been beating my head in the wall all evening on this, can someone give me some idea how I can get WatiN to TypeText into this text box? It is disabled until a radio button is selected and I am at a loss.. I am still a bit new to all of this to go easy on me

```
<TR>
    <TD WIDTH="100">Billing ID</TD>
    <TD nowrap>
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="reg_type" VALUE="Biller" ONCLICK="disableSubmitter(); clearAll(); document.config_frmV_f5a46cc226670cb3a4d7e0f5a98703a0.vendor_ID.disabled=false;">
        <B>Vendor ID:</B>
    </TD>
    <TD WIDTH="100"><INPUT TYPE="textbox" SIZE="10" NAME="vendor_ID" ID="vendor_ID" DISABLED ONBLUR='setupAjax();' value=""></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Submitter ID</TD>
    <TD nowrap>
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="reg_type" VALUE="Submitter" ONCLICK="disableBiller(); clearAll(); document.config_frmV_f5a46cc226670cb3a4d7e0f5a98703a0.existing_Billing_ID.disabled=false;">
        <B>Billing ID:</B>
    </TD>
    <TD WIDTH="100">
        <INPUT TYPE="textbox" SIZE="10" NAME="existing_Billing_ID" ID="existing_Billing_ID" DISABLED ONBLUR='setupAjax();' value=""></TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="ff_option" VALUE="N"></TD>
</TR>
```

Here is the JavaScript for the onblur command to enable the textbox

```
function setupAjax()
{
    var sendStr = "";

    if(document.config_frmV_f5a46cc226670cb3a4d7e0f5a98703a0.reg_type[1].checked && document.config_frmV_f5a46cc226670cb3a4d7e0f5a98703a0.vendor_ID.value.length > 0)
    {
        document.config_frmV_f5a46cc226670cb3a4d7e0f5a98703a0.existing_Billing_ID.value = "";
        sendStr += 'reset=false&vendor_ID=' + document.config_frmV_f5a46cc226670cb3a4d7e0f5a98703a0.vendor_ID.value;
        sendStr += '&existing_Billing_ID=';

    }
    else if (document.config_frmV_f5a46cc226670cb3a4d7e0f5a98703a0.reg_type[2].checked && document.config_frmV_f5a46cc226670cb3a4d7e0f5a98703a0.existing_Billing_ID.value.length > 0)
    {
        document.config_frmV_f5a46cc226670cb3a4d7e0f5a98703a0.vendor_ID.value = "";
        sendStr += 'reset=false&existing_Billing_ID=' + document.config_frmV_f5a46cc226670cb3a4d7e0f5a98703a0.existing_Billing_ID.value;
        sendStr += '&vendor_ID=';
    }
    else 
    {
        return;
    }
```

I have tried to select by Id, Name, Index, you name it and I still cannot populate it despite the fact I can touch every other element on the page.. I am able to find it using the Element and it will report back the name however I cannot figure out how to populate the box using Elements

Comment: This isn't Java, this is JavaScript. Java is to JavaScript as what car is to carpet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured a work around out for the problem by using JavaScript, working like a charm now!

```
         StringBuilder js = new StringBuilder();
            js.Append(@"var myTextField = document.getElementById('vendor_ID');");
            js.Append(@"myTextField.setAttribute('value', '201153');");
            ie.RunScript(js.ToString());
```

Comment: Mark, this is fantastic! A great solution that opened my eyes to the power of RunScript. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Question:  Are you trying to enter a value in the textfield while it is disabled?

You won't (or at least shouldn't) be able to do something like mybrowser.TextField("myFieldID").TypeText("words go here") until the TextField is enabled.

**Pseudocode**

1. Click the radio button
2. Wait for the textfield to become enabled
3. Type text in the textfield

Comment: No it should be enabled, as soon as the radio button is clicked it just stops and eventually crashes. I even put a Thread.Sleep(5000) prior to doing the TypeText command and to be sure it was not still disabled, while it was sleeping, I could type in the field. Has me completely stumpped.